# "Unnamed" actions on Rhythmbox's icon right-click menu

Tags: gnome, .desktop, rhythmbox

I'm using Rhythmbox 3.4.7 and as you can see on the picture bellow, there are some *Unnamed* options on Rhythmbox's icon right-click menu:

> [image: screenshot showing "Unnamed" actions]

I've tried to copy `org.gnome.Rhythmbox.desktop` and `org.gnome.Rhythmbox.device.desktop` files data from [Rhythmbox's GitLab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/rhythmbox) to `/usr/share/applications` (same `.desktop` files), but nothing has changed.

Here are my system's details:

> [image: system details]

I guess that something is wrong with `[Desktop Action ...]` entries:

> [image: screenshot of .desktop file showing "Desktop Action" entries]

Does anyone have any clue on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution. `[Desktop Action ...]` entries were missing the `Name` properties:

> [image: screenshot showing the correct "Desktop Action" entries]

Comment: Thank you. I sent this patch to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/2055783